# Все перестановки подмножества флагов

Tags: python, алгоритм

У меня есть набор бинарных флагов произвольного размера в виде числа `int`.

Например, число "18" < `2**5` => минимум 5 флагов.

Мне нужно найти все сочетания установленных флагов, по довольно замороченной схеме. Я лучше приведу пример и покажу, что хочу получить.
Я хочу написать генератор, который получает на вход число, и возвращает все комбинации **ТОЛЬКО установленных бит этого числа***. Например, рассмотрим число 18:

```
>>> bin(18)
'0b10010'
```

Я хочу сделать генератор, который будет возвращать следующее:

```
yield [True, False, False, True, False] # исходное число
yield [False, False, False, True, False] # первый флаг установлен в 'False'
yield [True, False, False, False, False] # только второй флаг установлен в 'False'
yield [False, False, False, False, False] # оба флага установлены в `False`
```

1. Изменяться могут только единицы, которые были в исходном числе.
2. Порядок перебора флагов важен, флаги перебираются **слева направо**.
3. Генерируемая последовательность не содержит повторений.
4. Комбинация, в которой выключено два флага должна идти всегда после любой комбинации, в которой выключен лишь один флаг.
   То есть

```
[True, True, False, True]
```

лучше, чем

```
[True, False, False, True]
```

и чем

```
[True, True, False, False]
```

Поэтому генератор должен выплюнуть комбинации, которые наиболее близки к исходной последовательности раньше.

Меня устроит, если вместо списка будут возвращаться числа `int`. Для моего примера:

```
yield 18
yield 2
yield 16
yield 0
```

Зачем это нужно? Я ищу наиболее близкую (в метрике Левенштейна (без перестановок соседей)) комбинацию набора исходных данных для обучения нейронной сети для предсказания определённого набора. Флаги - это наличие/отсутствие столбца в исходных данных. Я прогоняю полученное число через предикат, чтобы понять, подойдёт оно мне или нет.

Алгоритм CPU_Bound (требователен к асимптотической сложности).

---

---

В итоге, пользуясь ответами @MBo и @Stanislav Volodarskiy, я использовал следующий код (Критика всегда приветствуется!):

```
from itertools import combinations

def gen_submasks(n:int):
    def gen_bases(n:int):
        while n > 0:
            yield (base := 1 << n.bit_length() - 1)
            n = n ^ base
            
            # alternative syntax:
            # base = 1 << n.bit_length() - 1
            # yield base
            # n ^= base
    
    for count in range(n.bit_count()):
        for combination in combinations(gen_bases(n), count):
            yield n - sum(combination)
    
    yield 0

def main():
    n = 41
    for submask in gen_submasks(n):
        print(bin(submask)[2:].zfill(n.bit_length()))

main()

# 101001
# 001001
# 100001
# 101000
# 000001
# 001000
# 100000
# 000000
```

Comment: `10010` -> `x(1) = 10000, x(0) = 00010` => `y(3) = x(1) and x(0), y(2) = x(1) and 0, x(1) = 0 and x(0), y(0) = 0 and 0` Первое преобразование - выделение отдельных битов, второе - применение битовой маски длины = количеству единичных битов в исходном.

Comment: Пардон, не `and`, a `or`. Чёта задумался не о том. *нужно ли мне добавить пример, в котором больше двух флагов?* А нафига? это ж обычный бинарный перебор. единичка - OR-им маску соотв. бита, ноль - не OR-им.

Comment: Это если начальное = 31.

Comment: Я бы сказал, что мне нужно следующее (для числа 15):
1111, 0111, 1011, 1101, 1110, 0011, 0101, 0110, 1001, ...

Comment: Но число 15 состоит полностью из единиц. Для числа, в котором есть нули - нули останутся на своих местах всегда.

Comment: ` это ж обычный бинарный перебор` - не совсем. Пропущены комбинации, в которых нули меняются на единицы.

Comment: *Пропущены комбинации, в которых нули меняются на единицы.* Ну так именно поэтому и появляется предварительный этап сжатия единиц и генерации соотв. масок.

Comment: На выходе вам нужны числа или кортежи бит? И то и то можно сделать быстро, но преобразование формата съест больше времени чем генерация. Числа или кортежи?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy на выходе подойдёт и то и другое. Предпочтительно то, что будет быстрее.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Выделяем все установленные биты в виде кортежа. Затем перебираем подмножества битов уменьшая их мощность. Подмножество собирается из битов - это нужная нам маска:

```
def bits(n):
    """ bits of n ascending """
    while n > 0:
        b = n ^ (n & (n - 1))  # least bit of n
        yield b
        n ^= b                 # clear least bit


def masks(n):
    """ n submasks descending bit population, ascending value """
    bs = tuple(bits(n))

    def c_masks(c, i, m):
        if c == 0:
            yield m
        else:
            for j in range(c - 1, i):
                yield from c_masks(c - 1, j, m | bs[j])

    for c in reversed(range(len(bs) + 1)):  # subset cardinality
        yield from c_masks(c, len(bs), 0)


def main():
    n = int(input())
    w = len(f'{n:b}')
    for m in masks(n):
        print(f'{m:0{w}b}')


main()
```

> ```
> $ echo 18 | python masks.py
> 10010
> 00010
> 10000
> 00000
>
> $ echo 19 | python masks.py
> 10011
> 00011
> 10001
> 10010
> 00001
> 00010
> 10000
> 00000
> ```

Comment: Ответ даёт правильный)) Я посмотрю сложность, разберусь как работает и отмечу как ответ, если за это время не появится чего-нибудь более эффективного.

Answer (score 4):

Перебор подмасок:

```
def submasks(mask):
    sub = mask
    while sub:
        yield sub
        sub = (sub-1) & mask

mask = 41 #101001
for s in submasks(mask):
    print(s, bin(s)[2:])

41 101001
40 101000
33 100001
32 100000
9 1001
8 1000
1 1
```

Comment: Какая шикарная идея!

Comment: Но ведь это же обработка справа налево...

Comment: @maestro, не про порядок разговор, а про идею как быстро перебрать подмаски без жутких рекурсивных спусков.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, автор вопроса в пункте 2 явно указывает, что порядок перебора важен.

Comment: @maestro Направление не имеет значения, автор может переименовать/перевернуть свои флаги. А вот порядок по мощности - да, важен. Можно рекурсивно удалять по одному единичному биту, передавая результат дальше, получаем дерево вариантов с выводом по уровням - наверное, будет похоже на ответ Станислава.

Comment: Правильная последовательность для числа 41 - 101001, 001001, 100001, 101000, 000001, 001000, 100000, 000000

Comment: @MBo порядок имеет значение, потому что переворот - лишняя операция O(n). В вашем случае, извините, я даже не понимаю, что я должен перевернуть, чтобы получить правильный ответ.

Comment: @Aycon Нет, нужную вам последовательность (по мощности множества) не получите, ваш пункт 4 я поздно увидел. Однако ответ оставил как пример эффективной генерации всех битовых подмасок.

Comment: @MBo возможно тогда я его и добавил. Хорошо, спасибо, пусть будет. Но как ответ, я его не отмечу.